# Running OpenFoam command: paraFoam -> Error 420: paraView: not found

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I have lately installed OpenFoam v.2212.0 on UBUNTU 22.04.0. All the other OpenFoam commands work fine for me, but as soon as I type "paraFoam", I get the following error:

---

```
Invalid $PV_PLUGIN_PATH and -plugin-path= not defined

No supplementary ParaView/OpenFOAM reader modules

Using builtin reader: paraFoam -vtk

Created temporary 'damBreak.foam'

/usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/bin/paraFoam: 420: paraview: not found
```

---

Installation Path: */usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/bin/paraFoam* (I have navigated myself there using terminal commands and it is there where it needs to be)

Command typed in '.bashrc' prior to installing as per installation instructions:

*source /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/etc/bashrc*